# ExtJS - JavaScript assets specified in app.json not being loading?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I have the following references in my app.json file

```
"js": [
    {
        "path": "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js",
        "remote": true
    },
    {"path": "resources/debug.js"},
    {"path": "resources/Resources.js"}
],
```

The resources/Resources.js file contains the following code:

```
console.log("Resources.js loaded.")
var MCC = MCC || {};
MCC.Strings = (function () {
//private
//public
return {
         myProp: "myValue"
};
})();
```

However, the file `Resources.js` never seems to load.  Certainly the call to `console.log('Resources.js loaded.")` is never made.

I admit, I don't really understand the app.json file very well, but I thought the references in this file would be loaded automatically.  Any ideas why this is not the case?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. The resources, which are defined in app.json working only for sencha touch apps, but not for ExtJS apps. I was able do load the files which I need as commented require declarations at the beginning of the man view:

```
// @require /path-to/external-file.js
```

Comment: Are you using sencha cmd?

Comment: Is there any documentation for this that I can reference?  I'm having trouble finding it on their website.